# ASP.NET 1.0 MVC APPLICATION

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

using VS 2008 i created a clean asp.net  MVC application project and changed nothing ,
on my computer all works fine.after i uploaded to the server i'm facing a problem.

the LogOn.aspx page code is from the VS2008 mvc applocation template with no modification ,

Log On

### Log On

Please enter your username and password. <%= Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") %> if you don't have an account.

<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("username") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("username") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <%= Html.Password("password") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("password") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= Html.CheckBox("rememberMe") %> <label class="inline" for="rememberMe">Remember me?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

and its working on my local asp.net  Dev server and also on a GoDaddy Server, but when i moved it to  a new web server it not functioning  correctly.

when i submit the LogOn page , a simple 
page on my local machine all working fine and i  and i get  :

```
Request URL:http://91.202.171.55/$sitepreview/powergroup.co.il/Account/LogOn
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Referer:http://91.202.171.55/$sitepreview/powergroup.co.il/Account/LogOn
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2149
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Jun 2010 18:51:43 GMT
Expires:Thu, 24 Jun 2010 18:51:44 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version:1.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

but when test the production server the page is not being submitted and the AccountController LogOn method is never invoked.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)

    {

        if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
        {
            return View();
        }

        FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

instead the AccountController   LogOn GET method is invoked

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Headers:

```
Request URL:http://91.202.171.55/$sitepreview/powergroup.co.il/Account/LogOn
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Referer:http://91.202.171.55/$sitepreview/powergroup.co.il/Account/LogOn
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2149
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Jun 2010 18:51:43 GMT
Expires:Thu, 24 Jun 2010 18:51:44 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version:1.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: How do you *know* that the LogOn() method is being called, and you're not falling into the first statement of the LogOn(...) method?  If validation fails, it just loads the form again.  Is your authentication stuff set up correctly on the server?

Comment: since the request  is always sent in GET and also added some debugging log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick check but has the live server got the .mvc extension registered against  ISAPI?

Comment: im running IIS 7.0 - is registration needed ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are submitting the form through a GET request, while the LogOn action method you wanted to invoke is decorated by AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), which enables the action method to be called in response to POST requests. Just modify your logon FORM tag like this:

```
<form ... method="post">
```

Comment: using (Html.BeginForm() handles that